# Javascript cascade injection involving distinct domains

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-domain

#### Simply said:

Can an external Javascript code inject another script hosted on a third distinct domain in the page DOM ?

#### Ex:

Given **foo.com** website, having an html script tag with its src set to `http://bar.xyz/script.js`.
Can `script.js` inject `http://qux.net/abc.js` *(hosted on qux.com)*?

```
http://foo.com/

  <script src="http://bar.xyz/script.js"></script>

  // Content of bar.xyz/script.js:
  !(function(){
    var k = document.createElement('script')
        , s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    k.type='text/javascript'; k.async=true;
    k.src = document.location.protocol+'//qux.net/abc.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(k,s);
    //…
  })();
```

I could not get abc.js to be injected and no error/alert seams to pop into the console.
Does any security restriction policy apply here ?
I am still looking for articles or SO thread talking about this…
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; once Javascript code is running in your origin, it is completely indistinguishable from your own code and can do anything you can.

Comment: Thank you, so scripts can import third party scripts without any restriction in this context ? Then I guess my issue comes probably from brittle logic in between …